# Widget displayed on app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ds.cpuoverlay&hl=en

Tags: android

The app [Cool Tool - system stats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ds.cpuoverlay&hl=en) displays cpu information as an overlay on top of home screen. I have verified the panel is not a customised toast.

I did a lot of research but unable to sort out what kind of widget it is.

Can someone please help me in identifying the widget being used here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Intersting qestion. I also would like to know.

Comment: most likely it is a view added (using a service) via WindowManager (using SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission, etc).